# KOMA - Footnote for enclosure?

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, scrlttr2

How can I add footnotes to enclosures using `\encl`? The code below is not working.

```
\documentclass[version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Markus Kohm}
\opening{Dear Mr. Kohm,}
how can I add footnotes to enclosures\footnote{works}?
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosures: }
\encl{encl\footnote{not working}} % footnote is not showing
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (untested.)  Can you do `\encl{encl\footnotemark}\footnotetext{is working}`..?

Comment: @cgnieder -- No problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick workaround:

```
\footnotemark
\footnotetext{<text>}
```

For example:

```
\documentclass[version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Markus Kohm}
\opening{Dear Mr. Kohm,}
how can I add footnotes to enclosures\footnote{works}?
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosures: }
\encl{encl\footnotemark}%
\footnotetext{is working} %
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```